# RegEx replace second closing tag in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to replace the second closing tag `>` in an String `Something="<!-- comm --!><tag titi="string1" toto="string2">"` using regex in java.

```
Something.replaceFirst( "^?>","XXXX")
```

replace the first `>`

I would like to replace the second closing tag `>` after string2 to have this result

```
Something="<!-- comm --!><tag titi="string1" toto="string2"XXXX"
```

I'm not really familiar with regex. What am I must doing? Thanks

Comment: It's actually quite tricky to do what you're doing. You basically need to count the number of `>` instances, and then splice the string. Regex can only help you a little bit with this!
It looks like you're hacking some html. Maybe use a tool like jsoup which is built to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match everything, but use capturing groups, so you can paste everything back in around the `XXXX`.

```java
String something = "<!-- comm --!><tag titi=\"string1\" toto=\"string2\">";
System.out.println(something.replaceFirst("(^.+?>.+?)>(.*$)", "$1XXXX$2"));
```

- ( starts the first capturing group
- ^ anchors to the start of a line
- .+? matches one or more of any character as few times as it has to
- > matches '>' literally
- ) ends the first capturing group
- > matches '>' literally again, this is the only thing *not* in a capturing group
- ( starts capturing group 2
- .* matches 0 or more of any character
- $ anchors to the end of the line
- $1 refers to the first capturing group (everything before the second '>')
- $2 refers to the second capturing group (everything that might come after the second '>')

Comment: You can do this with a single `\K` right?: `.+?>.+?\K>`

Comment: Possibly, although I remember now java doesn't like \K very much - if I were you I'd scrap the solution I just gave you and I'll edit my answer with a more java-friendly one.

Comment: Updated my answer to use capturing groups, I think you'll find they work better in java.

Comment: That's odd...  it works for me.  Have you tried stripping it down to a simple test case?  I edited my code to include a `println`, try just copying that verbatim into your main method and see what happens.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I have another tag in the com
`Something="<!-- <comm> --!><tag titi="string1" toto="string2">"`
I think that I must Add `.+?>` in the $1 to have this `something.replaceFirst("(^.+?>.+?>.+?)>(.*$)", "$1XXXX$2")`

Comment: it works with 
`something.replaceFirst("(^.+?>.+?>.+?)>(.*$)", "$1XXXX$2")`
Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem!  Glad you got it to work, and thank you for accepting my answer